# Using Toolbar with Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, toolbar, android-actionbaractivity

Toolbar mainly should used with ActionBarActivity 
if I want to use it  by  Extends Activity it gives an error 
when I call

```
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I main Above I don,t want to use ActionBarActivity

Any help here , And what About Another kind Of Activities

Like FragmentActivity or Others .

Example to support FragmentActivity

```
 ActionBarActivity activity = (ActionBarActivity) getActivity();
 activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're extending Activity just use [setActionBar()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setActionBar%28android.widget.Toolbar%29). setSupportActionBar is for when your're using ActionBarActivity from the support library

Comment: Well it should work, if it doesn't then you're probably doing something wrong

Comment: setActionBar(toolbar);   Call requires  API 21 ,,,, I want to use it with all API

Comment: You can't. You'll need to extend ActionBarActivity or AppCompatActivity and use setSupportActionBar to support the majority of the APIs

Comment: I give you a vote up For Helping ,, but i think there is another way

Comment: @MaherIsmaail there is no other way. If you really wan't to support all version, you will have to make you're own Toolbar with you're own code.

Comment: i mean there is a another way

Comment: like Fragment Activity

Answer (score 0):

You have done little mistake .. you had to extend

> ActionBarActivity

not only

> Activity

class ..when you do error will be removed.

Comment: sorry for that .. got mistake but i think it can't be possible without using only Activity ..